# how to Increase or decrease spring session timeout on runtine?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently i'm working on a project that we need to increase or decrease session timeout after creating a session dynamically, i searched all over the internet and couldn't find a solution, all only i found was changing the timeout before creating. how can we do that?

Comment: If it is not possible to increase or decrease the session time during runtime, why not destroy the old session and make a new session with the required time set (either increased or decreased)?

Comment: I think you should keep your sessions in database and manipulate them in `Interceptor` or other your own custom methods.